# Can't open deployed Django web app on Azure container instance

Tags: django, docker, azure-devops, azure-container-instances

Run the below commands, all were successful, but can't open the web app on browser, how to fix it?

```
virtualenv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate
pip install Django
django-admin startproject demoproject
python manage.py runserver
--notes: checked the web app was running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
pip freeze > requirements.txt
--notes: add file "Dockerfile"
--notes: add file ".dockerignore"
docker build -t demoproject:v1.0 .
az login
az acr login --name xxtestcr
docker tag demoproject:v1.0 xxtestcr.azurecr.io/demoproject:v1.0
docker push xxtestcr.azurecr.io/demoproject:v1.0
az acr update -n xxtestcr --admin-enabled true
az container create -g xxtestrg --name test-ci --image xxtestcr.azurecr.io/demoproject:v1.0 --ports 80 443 --cpu 1 --memory 1.5 --dns-name-label xxtest-demoproject
```

*Dockerfile*:

```
FROM python:3.10.8

RUN mkdir /code

WORKDIR /code

COPY . /code/

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

*.dockerignore*

```
__pycache__
.venv/
Dockerfile
```

The app files:

[image]

Azure container instance overview:

[image]

But can't open the web app on browser:
4.147.67.11
xxtest-demoproject.australiaeast.azurecontainer.io

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application listens on port 8000, but your ACI listens on ports 80 and 443.

You can listen on several ports with ACI but can't redirect to a single port. If you want to forward 80 and 443 to 8000, you'll need to use App Gateway, for example.

Please try with:

```
az container create -g xxtestrg --name test-ci --image xxtestcr.azurecr.io/demoproject:v1.0 --ports 8000 --cpu 1 --memory 1.5 --dns-name-label xxtest-demoproject
```

then try `http://<ip/url>:8000`

Comment: Hi Vuillemot, you genius saved my day, thank you